# React native cross platform programming

Tags: react-native

I'm impressed by the performance of React native. And I tried to create a simple **login/register/password reset** project but I found it's difficult to make it work on both iOS and Android (UI part). Is there any **"Best practice guide"** document like those in angular, ionic? Because it's not easy:

- To decide the file structure of project, for example, MVC, MVVM
- To make it cross platform

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a "best practice guide" but I do have a suggestion for you.

You could look at [Snowflake - React-Native](https://github.com/bartonhammond/snowflake): it uses a  single code base for iOS and Android - it does the Registration, Login, Logout, Reset Password and Update Profile, the same things you've been working on. There are validation rules for the data entry fields too.

There is a lot of documentation and Jest tests. It also uses Redux, which is quite popular now, for state management. It might be helpful in your research and give you some ideas of how to approach React-Native and the structure of the app.

Full disclosure: I wrote Snowflake.

Comment: This is really great. I'll have a study on your code. Thanks.